# slick slider only working the first time in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm building an app in HTML5 with Jquery Mobile and I'm using the Slick slider for showing a gallery of images but it only works the firts time I change to the gallery page, the next ones it crashes.

```
$('#roller').on('pageshow',function(){
    console.log("TRIGGER");
    $('.divroller').slick({
        arrows:false,
        dots:false,
        infinite:false,
        slidesToShow:4,
        swipe:true,
        swipeToSlide:true,
        initialSlide:0
    });
});
```

the images are loaded from a JSON string that returns the html for the divroller div

Comment: Do you have the HTML that goes with this?

Comment: <div data-role="page" id="roller">
  <div class="container">
   <div data-role="header" class="row header">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
     <div class="linkinicio">
      <a href="#inicio">Inicio</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 divlogo">
     <img src="" class="img-responsive logorestaurante"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
     <div class="dividiomas">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row divroller">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: If you provide a [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing your problem you will likely get help a lot faster. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]. slick adds two classes (slick-initialized and slick-slider) to de divroller div the first time that $('#roller').on('pageshow') triggers. So for the other times to work, the both classes inserted by slick must be removed in order to trigger the slider again

Comment: Instead of removing the classes, can you just call the unslick method:  $('.divroller').slick('unslick'); and then reinitialize?